# Efficient mapping of values from one Numpy array to the cloesest value on another

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have two arrays: the 1st is a nested array of floats (which we will call the value array) and the 2nd is a 1d array of floats (which we will call the key array). The goal is to map each element within the value array to the numerically closest value on the key array.

To give some background, I am trying to map the weights of a CNN to discrete weights as part of a simulation project. The shape of the weights is dependent on the layer and network definition. In this particular case, I am working with a tf.keras.applications.ResNet50V2 network with CIFAR-10 as the dataset, which has weights that go from 3D to 1D. The weights are returned as nested lists with each index indicating the layer. The number of elements within the value array is very large when completely flattened

I currently have a working solution which I have included below, but I am wondering if anyone could think of any further optimizations. I keep getting warnings about the callback class taking longer than the actual training. This is a function that should be executed at the end of each training batch, so a little optimization can go a long way.

```
for ii in range(valueArray.size):
        # Flatten array to 1D
        flatArr = valueArray[ii].flatten()

        # Using searchsorted since our discrete values have been sorted
        idx = np.searchsorted(keyArray, flatArr, side="left")
        # Clip any values that exceed array indices
        np.clip(idx, 0, keyArray.size - 1, out=idx)

        flatMinVal = keyArray[idx]
        # Get bool array of idx that have values to the left (idx > 0)
        hasValLeft = idx > 0

        # Ensures that closer on left is an bool array of equal size as the original
        closerOnLeft = hasValLeft
        # Check if abs value for right is greater than left (Acts on values with idx > 0)
        closerOnLeftSub = np.abs(flatArr[hasValLeft] - keyArray[idx[hasValLeft]]) > \
            np.abs(flatArr[hasValLeft] - keyArray[idx[hasValLeft]-1])
        # Only assign values that have a value on the left, else always false
        closerOnLeft[hasValLeft] = closerOnLeftSub

        # If left element is closer, use that as state
        flatMinVal[closerOnLeft] = keyArray[idx[closerOnLeft]-1]
        # Return reshaped values
        valueArray[ii] = np.reshape(flatMinVal, valueArray[ii].shape)
```